# Python multi-inheritance. Is this a bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

In the example below, I expected to see:

```
CarChild1
CarChild2
```

But it prints:

```
CarChild1
CarChild1
```

The scenario is that I have a class that inherits 2 classes.
It needs to call the `run()` function of both of the parent classes in the right sequence, but for some reason, it only calls the first parent class's function.

The sample code below illustrates the issue:

```
class CarChild1:
    def run(self):
        self._print_name()

    def _print_name(self):
        print('CarChild1')

class CarChild2:
    def run(self):
        self._print_name()

    def _print_name(self):
        print('CarChild2')

class CarChild3(CarChild1, CarChild2):
    def run(self):
        CarChild1.run(self)
        CarChild2.run(self)

carChild3 = CarChild3()
carChild3.run()
```

Comment: If you especially want `CarChild2` to use the `print_name` method declared in `CarChild2`, you could call `CarChild2._print_name(self)`.

Comment: How shall I resolve this issue without changing all of the individual classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `self._print_name()` will call the `_print_name` method of the object based on its class hierarchy, not necessarily the one defined in the same class you are calling it from.

If you specifically want `CarChild2` to use the `_print_name` method declared in `CarChild2`, you could call `CarChild2._print_name(self)`. Or you could just give your different `_print_name` methods different names, since you want them to work independently.

*Or* if you call your print method `__print_name` (with a double underscore prefix) instead of `_print_name` then Python will internally alter their names so that the right one is called in each class and cannot* be called outside of it. (The methods are then essentially private to the class.)

* <sub>They can, but only by working around the name-mangling mechanism</sub>